# How to get update query WriteResult in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, updates

I am doing an update in mongodb but not very familiar with how to get things done in mongodb.

```
Todo.update({}, {$set : { tags : []}}, false, true);
```

How do I get `WriteResult`? I want to know the `nMatched` and `nModified` value.

I tried the following but it doesnt work.

```
var updateResult = Todo.update({}, {$set : { tags : ['test']}}, false, true);
(function(updateResult){
    console.log('Size of match: ' + updateResult.nMatched);
    console.log('Size of modified: ' + updateResult.nModified);
})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, it's important to understand that `Todo.update` is an async function which delivers its results to a callback function rather than returning it.

But the Mongoose [`update`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update) function also takes its parameters in a different way than the shell.

So your code should look something like this instead:

```
Todo.update({}, 
            {$set: {tags: []}}, 
            {upsert: false, multi: true}, 
            function(err, numberAffected, rawResponse) {
    console.log('Number of docs modified: ' + numberAffected);
});
```

The `rawResponse` parameter to the callback contains the full response from Mongo, but that's really only useful when using `upsert`.

Comment: Can I access the `WriteResult` using promises?

Answer (score 1):

Here your problem due to the fact that `updateResult` is undefined in your self invoked anonymous function because you passing nothing to it. (also there is no `console.log` in mongoshell, but it is not so important). You have to pass your updateResult as a parameter to a function. Like this:

```
(function(r){
    print('Size of match: ' + r.nMatched);
    print('Size of modified: ' + r.nModified);
})(updateResult);
```

and then you will get something like this:

```
Size of match: 1
Size of modified: 0
```

Comment: Silly me. I am yet to get hang of javascript. Thanks btw.

Comment: I am afraid this didnt work as expected. Due to some promise related issue, both console.log print undefined.

Comment: Also, i am doing this in nodejs, using mongoose.